# In TypeScript, is it possible to convert a an any type value to a custom type and use a default value should the value not match?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a type like

```js
type MyType = "value1" | "value2"
```

and I have a value `x` of type `any`. Is there a way to coerce `x` to `MyType` in a way that returns some specified default value `d` if the value `x` doesn't fit the type `MyType`, and such that the TS compiler typechecks it?
Something along the lines of:

```js
let y: MyType = magicThatDoesWhatIWant(x, MyType, d)
```

This would then effectively produce something like the following JS code (upon compilation):

```js
let y;
switch (x) {
  case "value1":
     y = x
     break;
  case "value2":
     y = x
     break;
  default:
     y = d
}
```

Is there something like this in TS?

Comment: Do you want to generate code from types, or I didn't understood your question correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was hoping was possible

Comment: You cannot pass `MyType` as an argument to a function because typescript types don't exist at runtime so they can't be used as variables.  You do achieve what you want if `MyType` is derived from a variable or if it is an `enum`.  Do either of those work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to validate the type of an `any` variable.  You can combine that with setting a replacement value.

You cannot pass MyType as an argument to a function because typescript types don't exist at runtime so they can't be used as variables. You can achieve what you want if MyType is derived from a variable, as you can use that variable for run-time checking.

#### From an Array

We declare an immutable constant with the values of our type:

```
const strings = [ "value1", "value2" ] as const;
```

We say that `MyType` is the type of the elements of that array:

```
type MyType = (typeof strings)[number];
```

This is our type guard.  If the `any` variable `x` is contained in an array where all values have type `T`, then we assert that `x` is of type `T`.

```
function isInArray<T>(x: any, values: readonly T[]): x is T {
    return values.includes(x);
}
```

Now for your "magic".  We must pass an array of `values` to check against as well as a default value `d`.  We will know that whatever value we return has type `T`.

```
function castToType<T>(x: any, values: readonly T[], d: T): T {
    return isInArray(x, values) ? x : d;
}
```

Both `v1` and `v3` in this example have the type `"value1" | "value2"`.  `v1` is `"value1"` because that string matched our type.  `v3` is `"value2"` which was the default.

```
const v1 = castToType("value1", strings, "value2")
const v3 = castToType("value3", strings, "value2")
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mpl9bm)

#### From an Enum

The array method works with any union type.  If your values are `string` or `number` you can make use of Typescript [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) since these create both a type declaration and an object variable which we can use at run-time.

```
enum MyEnum {
    Value1 = "value1",
    Value2 = "value2",
}
```

We check in basically the same way, except that we use `Object.values` to get an array of valid enum values.

```
function isInEnum<T>(x: any, enumObj: Record<string, T>): x is T {
    return Object.values(enumObj).includes(x);
}

function castToType<T>(x: any, enumObj: Record<string, T>, d: T): T {
    return isInEnum(x, enumObj) ? x : d;
}

const v1 = castToType("value1", MyEnum, MyEnum.Value2)
const v3 = castToType("value3", MyEnum, MyEnum.Value2)
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/m3Aybw)